# ncmpcpp can't find my music

Tags: files, music, mpd, ncmpcpp

I finally got ncmpcpp and MPD to work, but ncmpcpp won't find my music. I've restarted MPD multiple times, installed mpc and run `mpc update`, pressed U inside ncmpcpp, restarted my machine, tried with the music on my external HDD, tried with a symlink, and tried with music on my internal HDD, and none of them work. My mpd configuration is below.

```
user               "tay"
bind_to_address    "localhost"
port               "6601" #6600 is already taken by something
#music_directory    "/media/tay/External/Music"
music_directory    "/home/tay/Desktop/Avenged Sevenfold"
playlist_directory "/home/tay/.mpd/playlists"
db_file            "/home/tay/.mpd/mpd.db"
log_file           "/home/tay/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file           "/home/tay/.mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file         "/home/tay/.mpd/mpdstate"

audio_output {  
    type  "pulse"
    name  "MPD"
} 

# Symbolic link behavior ######################################################
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following 
# symbolic links outside of the configured music_directory.
#
follow_outside_symlinks "yes"
#
# If this setting is set to "yes", MPD will discover audio files by following
# symbolic links inside of the configured music_directory.
#
follow_inside_symlinks      "yes"
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that the path to your music folder/directory is correct in `/home/USERNAME/.mpd/mpd.conf`, by dragging your music folder into a terminal window and copy/paste the output to `music_directory    ""`

```
music_directory    "/home/tay/Desktop/Avenged Sevenfold"
```

is set as your active path, but it seems, that

```
music_directory    "/media/tay/External/Music"
```

is the correct one, which is inactive, due to the `#`.

1. Delete one of the two `music_directory` paths, since you have two
2. Make sure, it is ative, meaning without the `#`and your path is correct
3. Update your Database again, pressing `u` inside of mpc.

If that doesn't work for you, please post any error messages you might get during this process.